# Creating another kotlin class file

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have issues creating another kotlin class file in my src folder in IntelliJ, please how do I go about this cos I've made a lot of findings but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome,  What are those issues, please update the post  with all the issues you have.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `Right click -> New` on the directory should do it... do you have errors when doing that?